# PHP multi array (JSON) from SQL query on three tables

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, multidimensional-array

I hope someone can help me with this specific problem.
I'm new to PHP and MySQL but I'm trying as best as I can. Also, I know that probably similar questions have been asked, but unfortunately I tried every angle I could think of to modify those tutorials/answers to suit my needs, but unfortunately I've failed miserably..

So, here's my problem: I have 3 MySQL tables(contacts, phone numbers, and phone types) for simple phonebook, structured like this:

```
|ID  |name  |          |ID  |cID  |tID  |number|          |ID  |type  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1    John              1    1     2     123456            1    Home
 2    Mary              2    2     1     234567            2    Mobile
 3    Sue               3    1     3     213234            3    Work
                        4    2     2     444321            
                        5    3     2     555543
```

The first table contains contact names, second holds the number details, and third is "static" table for referencing phone number types.

Now, I'm creating an api for simple crud app in PHP and I'm stuck at creating the array that will give me the result structured as I envisioned:

```
[
 {"ContactID": 1,
  "ContactName": "John",
  "PhoneNumbers": {
     "PhoneNumberID": 1,
     "PhoneType":     2,
     "PhoneNumber":   123456
     }
 },
 {...},
 {...}
]
```

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT contacts.*, pt.type, pn.number, pn.id
FROM contacts
        LEFT JOIN phonenumbers pn ON c.ID = pn.cID
        LEFT JOIN phonetypes pt ON pn.tID = pt.ID
```

And now I'm stuck at PHP syntax for creating the array mentioned above. Can you help point me in the right direction please?

Also, as this is a small assignment demonstrating the CRUD functions, I'm not sure about my database, is the three table structure OK? Do I need to change it to something else?

Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Shouldn't `PhoneNumbers:` be an array of objects, not a single object?

Comment: Oops, you're right. Probably I should go to bed because I'm of no use anymore. It's 2:30am here..G'night good people, I hope tomorrow will be better than today...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the tables have `ID` columns, you need to use an alias in the SQL to distinguish `phonenumbers.id` from `contacts.id`. So change the query to:

```
SELECT contacts.*, pt.type, pn.number, pn.id AS phoneid
FROM contacts
LEFT JOIN phonenumbers pn ON c.ID = pn.cID
LEFT JOIN phonetypes pt ON pn.tID = pt.ID
```

Here's the code assuming you're using PDO; mysqli will be similar.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['ContactID']]) {
        // If this is the first row for this contact, create an entry in the results
        $result[$row['ContactID']] = array(
            'ContactID' => $row['ID'],
            'ContactName' => $row['name'],
            'PhoneNumbers' => array()
        );
    }
    // Add this phone number to the `PhoneNumbers` array
    $result[$row['ContactID']]['PhoneNumbers'][] = array(
        'PhoneNumberID' => $row['phoneid'],
        'PhoneType' => $row['type'],
        'PhoneNumber' => $row['number']
    );
}
$result = array_values($result); // Convert from associative to indexed array
// Convert to JSON
echo json_encode($result);
```

The resulting JSON will look like this:

```
[
 {"ContactID": 1,
  "ContactName": "John",
  "PhoneNumbers": [
    {
     "PhoneNumberID": 1,
     "PhoneType":     "Mobile",
     "PhoneNumber":   "123456"
    },
    {
     "PhoneNumberID": 3,
     "PhoneType":     "Work",
     "PhoneNumber":   "213234"
    }
 },
 {...},
 {...}
]
```

`PhoneNumbers` is an array of all the phone numbers, and `PhoneType` is the type name, not its ID. If you only want the type ID, you don't need to join with `phonetypes`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar! Exactly what I was looking for, working like a charm!